# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054 Unknown column... in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, insert-update, mysql-error-1054

I can't get my head round this...

Controller:

```
public function update()
{
    $string = 'xml/gzip';
    $xml    = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://$string");
    foreach ($xml->merchant as $merchant) {
        $merchant_name = $merchant['name'];
        $merchant_id = $merchant['id'];
        $data1          = array(
              'merchant_id' => $merchant_id,
              'merchant_name' => $merchant_name
        );
        $this->load->model('Administration_model');
        $this->Administration_model->insert_merchants($data1);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function insert_merchants($data1)
{
    $this->db->insert('merchants', $data1);
}
```

The `foreach` loop in my controller is running data from an xml spreadsheet, and as the error says - the values '911' and 'website.com' SHOULD be the inserted values... So why is it determining 'website.com' as a 'field list'?

Error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'website.com' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `merchants` (`merchant_id`, `merchant_name`) VALUES (911, website.com)
```

Would it have anything to do with the fact that `merchant_id` is a primary column and this is technically a duplicate entry... And if so, any tips on how to add "ON DUPLICATE KEY..." functionality?

Comment: Even if it doesnot matters, load your model in the starting of the function and not inside the loop. Doesnot matters in the sense that if the model is already loaded, `CI` will not load it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote strings, else it thinks you are referring to column names.

```
INSERT INTO `merchants` (`merchant_id`, `merchant_name`) VALUES (911, 'website.com')
```

Comment: but `$this->db->insert` does that automatically when an array is passed...

Comment: and I just noticed this was like 5 years ago... smh

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look like it has any problems with it. I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of CodeIgniter, currently 3.1.5, and re-running your code.

```
$data = array(
    'merchant_id' => 911,
    'merchant_name' => 'website.com',
);

$this->db->insert('merchants', $data);
```

If you still have problems, try hard coding a value and put the let us know what happens.

As for your duplicate key issue, CodeIgniter 3.1.5 has a replace function which updates on a duplicate key. *Do keep in mind the performance loss of using this, as for a large import this could be very slow. For large datasets, look into batching the queries.*

```
$data = array(
    'merchant_id' => 911,
    'merchant_name' => 'website.com',
);

$this->db->replace('merchants', $data);
```